# rails - efficiently selecting one object with id not in a known set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a group blog that is moderated by the community.  When a user visits the `moderate` page, he is served up a random post that he has not yet moderated, and asked whether or not the post should appear.

So, the relevant objects are `Post`, `User`, and `Moderation`.  A `Moderation` has a `post_id` and a `user_id`.  I want to find a post from the set `Post.all` where there does not exist a `Moderation` object corresponding to that post and the current user.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?  I *could* get all of the moderations for that user, and then use `map` to get all of the posts that the user moderated, and then query the posts database as (pseudocode) `Post.find(:conditions => "id != [list of posts already moderated])` but I'm worried that might be slow?  Is there a faster way?

Also, would it be a good idea to cache this somehow?  Maybe by getting all posts that haven't been moderated, and saving that somewhere, and then when future calls to the `moderate` method are made, check that cache first and serve up a post (and remove that post from the cache), and only checking again for more posts if the cache is empty?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off top of my head:

```
Post.all(:joins => 'LEFT OUTER JOIN moderations m ON p.id=m.post_id AND m.user_id != #{id}')
```

Comment: Using `:joins` will make returned posts read only. Pass `:readonly => false` as well if it is not desired. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001777

Comment: I think it's any ANSI-SQL rdbms-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Ruby and thought I'd have a go at writing a program to do this, the end result is pretty bad in my opinion, but I thought I'd post the relevant part here anyway:

```
posts - moderations.select{|x| x.user_id == current_user}.collect{|x| x.post_id}
```

Comment: Avoid loading all the records and selecting/mapping it in your application. All that should be done in database, which would return you only relevant records. See ActiveRecord docs how to do it.